# DjangoRestFramework GET and POST many-to-many objects through angularjs

Tags: angularjs, django-rest-framework

I feel like I'm missing something crucial in rest framework that will help me understand this but so far browsing the documentation has not enlightened me.

I have a model `Circuit` that can have multiple `Component` models linked to it, this many to many relationship goes through a `CicuitHasComponent` table. It can also have sub-circuits, so a many to many relationship with itself through `CircuitHasCircuit` table. I want to show a detail view for the `Circuit` (using angular JS on the front end) that lists all the `Component`s and sub-`Circuit`s, and allows me to build new sub-object resources in the angular JS and post them. So I have the following serializers

```
class ComponentSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):    
    class Meta:
        model = Component
        fields = (
            'id', 'name'
        )


class CircuitHasComponentSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CircuitHasComponent
        fields = (
            'circuit',
            'component'
        )


class CircuitHasCircuitSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CircuitHasCircuit
        fields = (
            'circuit',
            'subcircuit'
        )


class CircuitSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    components = CircuitHasComponentSerializer(many=True)
    subcircuits = CircuitHasCircuitSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Circuit
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'components',
            'subcircuits'
        )
```

I have corresponding `ModelViewSet`s for each serialiser, but I am not sure on the neatest way to GET a specific subset of `CircuitHasComponent` (f.e.) objects for a given `Circuit` ID. Nor am I sure how to POST to the `CircuitHasComponent` view using JS models of the corresponding `Circuit` and `Component`.

Should I be using a nested method for this? or should things be broken down further?

Comment: Check that you really need M2M. May be it is enough to add `parent_circuit` FK to `Circuit` model. Because sub-circuit can't have multiple locations. The same is for `Component`.

Comment: I would prefer to get rid of `CicuitHasComponent`, `CircuitHasCircuit`, `CircuitHasComponentSerializer`, `CircuitHasCircuitSerializer`. Make regular M2M without `through` or just FK. Add `components` field to `CircuitSerializer`. This field should contain components ids. POSTing it can create relations.

Comment: Thanks guys, I should add that the model architecture was not my code so I was attempting to work around it but you might be right and redoing the models is going to be simpler all round

Comment: the M2Ms are needed due to circuits being included in multiple other circuits etc same with components, but I think rest framework is falling over when trying to get the relation automatically